# How to Develop alexa to speak latest response again

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

In Details:
Example: 
user:- asks About Cricket News.
Alexa:- Reads about the new.
If users says come again or replay
user: Come again.
Alexa: Must read it again what it spoke earlier.

How to handle this situation using webhooks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `sessionAttributes` to keep track of the last response that Alexa spoke. Whenever you return a response just store the speech and re-prompt in `sessionAttributes` and whenever a `ComeAgainIntent` is triggered, take the value from the `sessionAttributes` and respond accordingly.

Ex:

```
...
"sessionAttributes": {
    "lastResponse": {
       "speech": "This was my last speech",
       "reprompt": "This was my lst reprompt"
    }
 }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time before building the response store the response as **lastSpeech** in session attributes and write a **comeAgainIntent** or use **amazon.REPEAT** intent to repeat the response by getting **lastSpeech** from session attributes.